# Two Table Views in Single View Controller: Show the View first before Loading Data

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a Main View Controller that calls CategoryAndItemController through a button.

I have 2 UITableViewController inside the CategoryAndItemController.

Here's the viewDidLoad method codes:

```
if enter code here(categoriesController == nil) {
    categoriesController = [[CFCategoriesTableViewController alloc] init];
}
if (itemsController == nil) {
    itemsController = [[CFItemsTableViewController alloc] init];
}

[categoriesTable setDataSource:categoriesController];
[itemsTable setDataSource:itemsController];

[categoriesTable setDelegate:categoriesController];
[itemsTable setDelegate:itemsController];

categoriesController.view = categoriesController.tableView;
itemsController.view = itemsController.tableView;
```

What I need is to display the CategoryAndItemController.view then request for the data once I'm inside that view.

Right now, when I press the Button to call CategoryAndItemController, the view will only appear after all the data have been fetched and there will be a 2-3seconds time before CategoryAndItemController.view will appear.

I need to show the CategoryAndItemController.view first then just add a UIActivityIndicatorView while the data is loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code  in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {

      UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]   ini

        tWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];
                activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
                activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
               activityIndicator.center=  self.view.center
                [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator]

             [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(call_progress) withObject:nil];
    }

    -(void)call_progress
    {

       // web service code:

       [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
       [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

Comment: CategoryAndItemController is not showing until all the data is fetched. :( the botton is just highlighted and not immediately showing the next controller

Comment: put all code inside call_progress and my  check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to shift the code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear.

Add the loader in viewDidLoad.